# Heartbeat timeout in gevent-socketio

Tags: gevent-socketio

I use gevent-socketio in my application. I need to get information about user disconnected even if he didn't finish session properly (calling `socket.disconnect()` from JS.) As I see from [docs](https://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/server.html), SocketIOServer constructoor has parameter *heartbeat_interval*, but I don't see it in code. As I understood, documentation is outdated - its version 0.3.1, but version of code is 0.3.5-rc2 (and it's only available).

How can I set heartbeat timeout in gevent-socketio?

Thanks,
Boris.

Comment: It depends how you launch your gevent-socketio server. E.g. I work with django and use this a startup command: https://github.com/dmpeters/pcloud/blob/master/status/management/commands/runserver_socketio.py#L53 so that's where you can add your heartbeat_interval kwarg.